# Encryption sorted...Decryption is close to finished - python 3.4.1

Tags: python-3.4

I can encrypt fine. That works will numbers, spaces and upper and lower case. However, when I set my code to decrypt the encrypted message, the code, for some reason, thinks that the decrypted message is empty. It prints an empty space. I'm not explaining it very well, but if you run the code you will understand what I am on about. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

```
    alphabetL = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
alphabetC = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
number = '0123456789'
space = ' '
Ll = len(alphabetL)
Lc = len(alphabetC)
Ln = len(number)
Lall = Ll + Lc + Ln
Question1 = input("Hello, please insert the message you want encrypted: ")
key1 = int(input("Please insert the key you want used [Keep between 1 and 26]: "))
cipher = ''
cipher2 = ''


for A in Question1:
    if A in alphabetL:
        cipher += alphabetL[(alphabetL.index(A)+key1)%Ll]
    elif A in alphabetC:
        cipher += alphabetC[(alphabetC.index(A)+key1)%Lc]
    elif A in number:
        cipher += number[(number.index(A)+key1)%Ln]
    elif A in space:
        cipher += space
    else:
        print ("Error, please use abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
print (cipher)

Question2 = input("Would you like to decrypt the message? [Y/N]: ")
if Question2 == "Y":
    for A in cipher2:
        cipher2 += cipher[(cipher(A)-key1)%(len(cipher))]
    print (cipher2)
```

Comment: you never assign anything to cipher2, except the initial empty string, so `for A in cipher2` has NOTHING to do. perhaps that should be `for A in cipher`? (note the LACK of a `2`).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it hasn't seemed to have an effect. Thank you for trying though.